# JButton, JLabel, JTextArea is flapping while the background color alpha value is set to less then 255 (200)

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

I am trying to set the background of a JTextArea transparent with alpha value 200 and added to a LayerPan, which support Z index, the behind of the JTextArea is JPanel which is using for playing video, in the front is a JTextArea which is using to show some text, everything works well, but the JTextArea background is flapping. For better understanding the question please look at the image below:

**Case 1: Normal**
[image]

**Case 2: Abnormal**
[image]

In the second case, you will see that the background is not correct, it is something that I don't want. What can be the problem?

Comment: How are you displaying the video?

Comment: @MadProgrammer it is easy. Just read video frame by frame and then draw the frame on JPanel and repaint.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure you weren't using a heavy weight component or vlcj which has issues

Comment: It's really hard to know "why" without some kind of runnable example, are you using a alpha based color for the background?

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes you are right. I also really don't know why. I tried many and many ways. It is just when starts to frames and repainting the panel. And also at the same time show some text in the text area. It starts flapping (means the background will show some part of panel which shows video frame) sometimes okay sometimes not. It is very annoying.

Comment: Swing doesn't support components with alpha based colors, they can only be opaque or transparent, you'll have to fake it by making it transparent and overriding its paintComponent ... I suspect camickrs answer will provide you with more information

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to set the background of a JTextArea transparent with alpha value 200

I've never tried playing with video and transparent background before but in general Swing does not properly support transparent backgrounds. The transparency breaks the painting rules since the component is neither fully opaque or transparent.

So basically you need to make sure the background of the parent component is painted first. Then you need to paint the background of your component to get the transparency.

Check out [Background With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for more information and a simple class that does this painting for you.